# Nav bar inside menu page

Tags: python, taipy

I am trying to set up a nav bar inside a menu control element page.

```
instance_md = """
# <strong>Data</strong> Upload
## Let's upload data now
"""

download_md = """
# <strong>Data</strong> download
## Let's download data now
"""

live = [
    ('download_md', 'Download'), 
    ('instance_md', 'Instance')
]
live_md = Markdown("user_interface/taipy/pages/live/live.md")

live.md
<center><|navbar|lov={live}|></center>
```

even though the nav bar is displayed the markdown contents are not available. Also when I click on instance it opens a new page.

info:

I already have a multi-page app with menu control to switch pages and in live_md I need to navigate bw multiple functionalities using the nav bar.

How can I fix this issue?

update:

to make this clear, my home page already contains menu control pages defined. now to make markdown separate I  have interact.py and interact.md where interact_md has a navbar and interact.py has download_md  and instance_md

```
    pages = {
        '/': root,
        "Home ":home_md,
        "Interact":interact_md,
    
     
    }
```

On the Interact page, I was trying to have a nav bar with( download, and upload) pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `/` in the lov like below. It is needed to navigate through the pages.

```py
live = [
    ('/download_md','Download'), 
    ('/instance_md', 'Instance')
]
```

[Documentation](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/navbar/)

Does it solve your issue? If not, please describe the ideal solution.

Comment: I already tried this. it's showing instance _md not found when clicked and also opens a new tab for the same even though it's not a link but rather a markdown page I am passing.
Home 
-Overview 
-dashboard 
Interact 
-create 
-upload 
-edit

home and interact are the menu bar pages and inside, I want to add other pages and switch using navbar.

Comment: Could you please provide your entire code? I cannot replicate your issue. It seems like it is due to the definition of your page.